# GCM does not register device when installed from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

Very weird...

I have downloaded and installed my Android app from Google Play. At some point I've uninstalled it.

Now, when I install it from Eclipse and not from Google Play, GCM does not provide me a registration ID for push notifications... It simply won't register my device...

What is the reason and can I do?

Will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: That's fine. It was my mistake. Onresume made me a lot of trouble, but anyway there's no problem with the GCM. My mistake. Thanks anyway